# How to Install Adapter in Tibco Database

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

How do I install the adapter for Tibco database? Where do I download it? 
I am using the Designer verssão 5.7.

Regards, 
R. Pereira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the installation files here: https://edelivery.tibco.com/storefront/browse.ep?cID=200366